# How to run or check output of many matlab scripts?

Tags: matlab

is there any efficient method or website to check the output of many m-files (matlab scripts) e.g. 300 m-file without running each one individual and check the final result as it will be very annoying ???

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [run command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html). Write another script that runs each of the scripts in question and does whatever checking/processing you want. Just iterate over your list of scripts. If they're all named similarly, you might just construct each filename. If they're all in the same location, just [get the list of files in that location](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html).